# How define priority for events in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone app using [Map Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Map control has `CenterChanged` and `ZoomLevelChanged` events.

When I change the `zoom` value for map, both events are raised (because the center changes as well).
But I want using only `ZoomLevelChanged` event, when I change `zoom` value.

How do I set priority for events if multiple events are available or how switch off `CenterChanged` event when `ZoomLevelChanged` is raised?

Any Solution/Demo/Link would be very much helpful for me.

Comment: Why do you need to switch it off? Are you handling it? If not just ignore it..

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define the priority for events, and you can't depend on the order of events.

I'm not a Windows Phone developer, but ask yourself: what if there were a zoom change at the same time as a *large* center change? You would need to handle both events, right? I would make that work, then make it work for the case of a zoom change with a small center change.

Comment: This kind of technique is used for touch screen handling in general, to differentiate between a drag and a touch - usually you set a threshold value to the drag and if it's below a certain amount you treat it as a touch.

Answer (score 0):

Events that happen "simultaneously" are added to the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) queue. If a single event sets "zoom" and then "center", the queue will contain the zoom event followed by the center event.

I'm not completely sure what you mean by defining priority. If you mean changing the order the event handlers are called, the only way to do this would be to modify the code that sets the two properties so that they are set in a different order. Once the event handlers are added to the queue, you can't reorder them.

If you want to handle only the first "simultaneous" event though, this should be possible by disabling the other handler until the end of the queue. Something like this:

```
// in ZoomLevelChanged handler:
_zooming = true;
mapControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _zooming = false)); 

// in CenterChanged handler:
if (_zooming) return;
// rest of implementation
```

[BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc190259%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) adds the action to the end of the queue, so the `_zooming` flag will only be reset once the immediate `CenterChanged` handler has been called and skipped, allowing subsequent `CenterChanged` events to be handled normally.